# How do I listen for an Admob interstitial ad load event?

Tags: unity, admob

I can show interstitial AdMob ads with the following code:

```
    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 300, 150, 50), "Load Interstitials"))
    {           
        interstitial.LoadAd(interstitialsRequest); 
    }

    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 400, 150, 50), "Show Interstitials"))
    {       
        if (interstitial.IsLoaded())
        {
            interstitial.Show();
        }
    }
```

That's all working well.

Now I want to attach a listener for when the interstitial ad has loaded. I checked all the available source files, but can't find the right listener method.

```
void onAdLoaded()
{
    print("Interstitial Ad Loaded");        
}

public void HandleAdLoaded(object sender)
{
    print("HandleAdLoaded event received.");       
    // Handle the ad loaded event.
}
```

I use [*googleads-mobile-plugins*](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-plugins/tree/master/unity) for Admob ads.

What listener should I be using?

Answer (score 3):

There are several different events that can be called from the interstitial, `AdLoaded`, `AdOpened`, `AdClosing`, and `AdClosed`. Unfortunately it appears this is as much interaction as you can have with the interstitial *that google exposes*.

Digging deeper, if we look at the [source](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-plugins/blob/master/unity/source/Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Api/InterstitialAd.cs) of `InterstitialAd`, then we find it inherits from [`IAdListener`](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-plugins/blob/master/unity/source/Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Common/IAdListener.cs), which only exposes the events

```
void FireAdLoaded();
void FireAdFailedToLoad(string message);
void FireAdOpened();
void FireAdClosing();
void FireAdClosed();
void FireAdLeftApplication();
```

At this point, you can add your own events. Then, simply reimplement them in `InterstitialAd`'s source.

Comment: Means if I write above methods in my custom script then it gets called. Am I right?

Comment: @Siddharth You would have to add the code that calls them in InterstitialAd's source... You *may* have to dig into the java source too